# Como se puede transformar esta consulta sql en postgresql a consulta en django

Tags: django, postgresql

Buen dia a todos:

Tengo la siguiente consulta en postgresql que devuelve el Id del ultimo contrato que un trabajador ha firmado con una empresa en el año 2016 (desde el 01/01/2016 al 31/12/2016), así como sus apellidos paterno y materno, nombre, fecha de inicio y fecha de término del último contrato firmado. Por ejemplo: Si el trabajador XYZ ha firmado 2 contratos en el año 2016, el primero de ellos desde el 05/01/2016 al 31/03/2016 y el segundo contrato desde el 01/06/2016 al 31/12/2016, la consulta devuelve la información relacionada al segundo contrato.

```
SELECT "rrhh_contrato"."id", "rrhh_contrato"."persona_id", "rrhh_persona"."apellido_paterno",
"rrhh_persona"."apellido_materno", "rrhh_persona"."nombre1","rrhh_persona"."nombre2","rrhh_persona"."nombre3","rrhh_persona"."nombre4","rrhh_contrato"."fecha_inicio", 
"rrhh_contrato"."fecha_fin"
FROM "rrhh_contrato" 
INNER JOIN "sistema_local" ON ("rrhh_contrato"."local_id" = "sistema_local"."id")
INNER JOIN "rrhh_persona" ON ("rrhh_contrato"."persona_id" = "rrhh_persona"."id") 
INNER JOIN (
SELECT "rrhh_contrato"."persona_id",MAX("rrhh_contrato"."fecha_fin") AS max_fecha
FROM "rrhh_contrato" 
INNER JOIN "sistema_local" ON ("rrhh_contrato"."local_id" = "sistema_local"."id") 
WHERE ("sistema_local"."producto_id" = 1 AND "rrhh_contrato"."fecha_fin" 
BETWEEN '2016-01-01'::date AND '2016-12-31'::date)
GROUP BY "rrhh_contrato"."persona_id"
ORDER BY "rrhh_contrato"."persona_id"
) R ON "rrhh_contrato"."persona_id" = R.persona_id AND "rrhh_contrato"."fecha_fin" = R.max_fecha
WHERE "sistema_local"."producto_id" = 1
ORDER BY "rrhh_contrato"."persona_id";
```

Mi pregunta es: Como se puede transformar esta consulta sql a consulta django.

Este es le parte del método que se encuentra en la vista de mi proyecto:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger

contratos = Contrato.objects.filter(fecha_fin__year=ejercicio, local__producto=1).order_by('persona__apellido_paterno','persona__apellido_materno','fecha_fin')

paginator = Paginator(contratos, 15)
page = request.GET.get('page')

try:
     contratos = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
     contratos = paginator.page(1)
     except EmptyPage:
contratos = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

return render(request, 'lista_contratos.html', { 'permisos_opciones' : permisos_opciones, 'estados' : estados, 'contratos' : contratos, 'ejercicios' : ejercicios, 'id_ejercicio' : id_ejercicio })
```

y lo de aquí es parte de la plantilla .html

```
<table id="tablaLstContratos" width="100%" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th style="text-align:center;">#</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Documento</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Fecha Inicio</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Fecha Fin</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Nombre Completo</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Tipo Contrato</th>
    </tr>
    {% for contrato in contratos %}
    <tr>
       <td style="text-align:center;">{{ forloop.counter0|add:contratos.start_index }}</td>
       <td style="text-align:center;">{{ contrato.persona.nro_documento }}</td>
       <td style="text-align:center;">{{ contrato.fecha_inicio|date:"d/m/Y" }}</td>
       <td style="text-align:center;">{{ contrato.fecha_fin|date:"d/m/Y" }}</td>
       <td style="text-align:justify-all;">{{ contrato.persona.apellido_paterno }} {{ contrato.persona.apellido_materno }}, {{ contrato.persona.nombre1 }} {{ contrato.persona.nombre2 }}</td>
       <td style="text-align:justify-all;">{{ contrato.tipo_contrato }}</td>
   </tr>
   {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Estos son los modelos:

```
class Persona(models.Model):
    tipo_documento = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    nro_documento = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    pais_documento = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    fecha_nacimiento = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    apellido_paterno = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    apellido_materno = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    nombre1 = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    nombre2 = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    nombre3 = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    nombre4 = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    sexo = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    nacionalidad = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    codigo_telefono = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=True, null=True)
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=9, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

class Contrato(models.Model):
    persona = models.ForeignKey(Persona)
    fecha_inicio = models.DateField()
    fecha_fin = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    local = models.ForeignKey('sistema.Local')
    ocupacion_producto = models.ForeignKey(Cargo)
    regimen_laboral = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    ocupacion_sunat = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    sctr_pension = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True)
    tipo_trabajador = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    tipo_contrato = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    jornada_atipica_acumulativa = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    jornada_trabajo_maxima = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    trabajo_horario_nocturno = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    sindicalizado = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    periocidad_ingreso = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    remuneracion = models.FloatField()
    situacion = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    estado_contrato = models.CharField(max_length=2, default='1')
    motivo_baja = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
    fecha_cese = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)

class Local(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    celular1 = models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True)
    celular2 = models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True)
    codigo_sunat = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    producto = models.ForeignKey(Producto)

class Producto(models.Model):
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    color_a = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    color_b = models.CharField(max_length=7,null=True)
    empresa = models.ForeignKey(Empresa)
```

Comment: Hola Carlos, por favor edita el código de tu pregunta usando el botón de formato `{ }`. Es recomendable también que agregues información sobre tus avances en el problema. Usa esta guía [mcve].

Comment: Hola, ya está editado el código

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a ignorar, *momentaneamente*, la consulta en SQL y la plantilla ya que no son relevantes en la pregunta y me voy a enfocar en lo que esperas como salida:

> el Id del ultimo contrato que un trabajador ha firmado con una empresa en el año 2016 (desde el 01/01/2016 al 31/12/2016), así como sus apellidos paterno y materno, nombre, fecha de inicio y fecha de término del último contrato firmado.

Para esto, vamos a trabajar con un [**Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) de tu problema:

```
# coding: utf-8
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Persona(models.Model):
    apellido_paterno = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    apellido_materno = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    nombre1 = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s %s" % (self.nombre1, self.apellido_paterno, self.apellido_materno)


class Producto(models.Model):
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.descripcion


class Local(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    producto = models.ForeignKey(Producto)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s - %s" % (self.nombre, self.producto)


class Contrato(models.Model):
    persona = models.ForeignKey(Persona)
    fecha_inicio = models.DateField()
    fecha_fin = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    local = models.ForeignKey('Local')

    def __str__(self):
      return "De %s a %s" % (self.fecha_inicio, self.fecha_fin)
```

Vamos a colocar el mínimo de datos para comprende el ejemplo:

```
u = Persona(nombre1='pedro', apellido_paterno='nada', apellido_materno='mas')
p = Producto(descripcion='jabón motita')
l = Local(nombre='bodega', producto=p)
c1 = Contrato(persona=u, fecha_inicio=datetime(2016,1,16), fecha_fin=datetime(2016,8,31), local=l)
c2 = Contrato(persona=u, fecha_inicio=datetime(2016,9,1), fecha_fin=datetime(2017,1,15), local=l)
c3 = Contrato(persona=u, fecha_inicio=datetime(2016,3,1), fecha_fin=datetime(2016,3,31), local=l)
```

Como puedes ver, la persona con `pk=1` tiene dos contratos, para poder revisar el ejemplo, vamos a buscar **el último contrato que terminó en el 2016**.

Primero vamos a filtrar por usuario:

```
>>> contrato = Contrato.objects.filter(persona=1)
>>> contrato
>>> <QuerySet [
      <Contrato: De 2016-01-16 a 2016-08-31>, 
      <Contrato: De 2016-09-01 a 2017-01-15>, 
      <Contrato: De 2016-03-01 a 2016-03-31>
    ]>
```

Ahora vamos a agregar el filtro del año 2016:

```
>>> contrato = contrato.filter(fecha_fin__year=2016)
>>> <QuerySet [
      <Contrato: De 2016-01-16 a 2016-08-31>, 
      <Contrato: De 2016-03-01 a 2016-03-31>
    ]>
```

Ahora, vamos a buscar el último contrato firmado en el 2016 (en el ejemplo es el último contrato *finalizado* en el 2016). Para eso usamos el filtro `latest()`.

```
>>> contrato
>>> <Contrato: De 2016-01-16 a 2016-08-31>
```

La consulta completa es así:

```
>>> contrato = Contrato.objects.filter(persona=u, fecha_fin__year=2016).latest('fecha_fin')
>>> contrato
>>> <Contrato: De 2016-01-16 a 2016-08-31>
```

El objeto resultante contiene los datos de `Persona` a los que podemos acceder sin ningún problema:

```
>>> contrato
>>> <Contrato: De 2016-03-01 a 2016-03-31>

>>> contrato.persona
>>> <Persona: pedro nada mas>

>>> contrato.fecha_fin
>>> datetime.date(2016, 3, 31)

>>> contrato.fecha_inicio
>>> datetime.date(2016, 3, 1)

>>> contrato.id
>>> 3
```

Por supuesto, puedes usar filtros que involucren otros campos de tu modelo usando [Expresiones F()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/models/expressions/) o consultas más complejas usando [Objetos Q](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects), consulta la documentación.